# Hide/unhide toolbar menu

Tags: android, menu, hide, toolbar, show

I want to can be able to hide/unhide programmatically the toolbar menu.

Because I couldn't find any information for that on net I use next code to remove menu from toolbar:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mToolbar.getMenu().clear();
```

How can I put it back programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out next code to hide menu:

```
 Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 mToolbar.getMenu().clear();
```

and next to unhide:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (!mToolbar.getMenu().hasVisibleItems()) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, mToolbar.getMenu());
}
```